# Showing class property value on click

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, this

I need to display the `this.name` in the console when clicking the button element.

I could replace inside `clicked()` and set `console.log(myBtn.name)` but I'd like this method to work with any object.

Is there a way to do it? When I click I get an empty string.

Thanks!

```js
class Button {
  constructor(name, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ref = document.getElementById(id);


    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.ref.addEventListener("click", this.clicked);
  }

  clicked() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

let myBtn = new Button('My button', "test");
```

```html
<button id="test">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Inside the click handler, `this` refers to the <button>, not `myBtn`. Use an arrow function: `this.ref.addEventListener("click", () => this.clicked());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was almost there

The problem in your code is what this mean in the callback

When the button is pressed `this` is the button unless you told it otherwise

```js
class Button {
  constructor(name, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ref = document.getElementById(id);


    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.ref.addEventListener("click", this.clicked.bind(this));
  }

  clicked() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

let myBtn = new Button('My button', "test");
```

```html
<button id="test">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Please check for duplicates before posting answers. Any JS question posted after 2015 is a duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisG all JS question after 2015? :)

Comment: Well, 99,99% of them ;) Spend a few months here (JS tag), and it's the same 30 questions over and over and over again. I'm serious.